# how to set text in center of a label control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in vb.net with developer express tools how do i set the text that will be displayed in the label control on my form should be displayed in the center from both sides horizontal and vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextAlign property should be set to MiddleCenter.

Comment: tn x! a lot that does the trick .. but by developer express tools the property is not called exactly like that